# How to parse json and replace a value in a nested json?

Tags: json, freemarker

I have the below json:

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "data":{
        "_id":"ABCD",
        "CNTL":{"XMN Version":"R3.1.0"},
        "OMN":{"dree":["ANY"]},
        "os0":{
            "Enable":true,"Service Reference":"","Name":"",
            "TD ex":["a0.c985.c0"],
            "pn ex":["s0.c100.c0"],"i ex":{},"US Denta Treatment":"copy","US Denta Value":0,"DP":{"Remote ID":"","cir ID":"","Sub Options":"","etp Number":54469},"pe":{"Remote ID":"","cir ID":""},"rd":{"can Identifier":"","can pt ID":"","uno":"Default"},"Filter":{"pv":"pass","pv6":"pass","ep":"pass","pe":"pass"},"sc":"Max","dc":"","st Limit":2046,"dm":false},
        "os1":{
            "Enable":false,"Service Reference":"","Name":"",
            "TD ex":[],
            "pn ex":[],"i ex":{},"US Denta Treatment":"copy","US Denta Value":0,"DP":{"Remote ID":"","cir ID":"","Sub Options":"","etp Number":54469},"pe":{"Remote ID":"","cir ID":""},"rd":{"can Identifier":"","can pt ID":"","uno":"Default"},"Filter":{"pv":"pass","pv6":"pass","ep":"pass","pe":"pass"},"sc":"Max","dc":"","st Limit":2046,"dm":false},
        "ONM":{
            "ONM-ALARM-XMN":"Default","Auto Boot Mode":false,"XMN Change Count":0,"CVID":0,"FW Bank Files":[],"FW Bank":[],"FW Bank Ptr":65535,"pn Max Frame Size":2000,"Realtime Stats":false,"Reset Count":0,"SRV-XMN":"Unmodified","Service Config Once":false,"Service Config pts":[],"Skip ot":false,"Name":"","Location":"","dree":"","Picture":"","Tag":"","PHY Delay":0,"Labels":[],"ex":"From OMN","st Age":60,"Laser TX Disable Time":0,"Laser TX Disable Count":0,"Clear st Count":0,"MIB Reset Count":0,"Expected ID":"ANY","Create Date":"2023-02-15 22:41:14.422681"},
        "SRV-XMN Values":{},
        "nc":{"Name":"ABCD"},
        "Alarm History":{
            "Alarm IDs":[],"Ack Count":0,"Ack Operator":"","Purge Count":0},"h FW Upgrade":{"wsize":64,"Backoff Divisor":2,"Backoff Delay":5,"Max Retries":4,"End Download Timeout":0},"Epn FW Upgrade":{"Final Ack Timeout":60},
        "UNI-x 1":{"Max Frame Size":2000,"Duplex":"Auto","Speed":"Auto","lb":false,"Enable":true,"bd Rate Limit":200000,"st Limit":100,"lb Type":"PHY","Clear st Count":0,"ex":"Off","pc":false},
        "UNI-x 2":{"Max Frame Size":2000,"Duplex":"Auto","Speed":"Auto","lb":false,"Enable":true,"bd Rate Limit":200000,"st Limit":100,"lb Type":"PHY","Clear st Count":0,"ex":"Off","pc":false},
        "UNI-POTS 1":{"Enable":true},"UNI-POTS 2":{"Enable":true}}
}
```

All I am trying to do is to replace only 1 small value in this super-complicated json. I am trying to replace the value of **os0** tags's **TD ex**'s value from ["a0.c985.c0"] to ["a0.c995.c0"].

Is freemarker the best way to do this? I need to change only 1 value. Can this be done through regex or should I use gson?

I can replace the value like this:

```
 JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(inputJson).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonElement jsonElement = jsonObject.get("data").getAsJsonObject().get("os0").getAsJsonObject().get("TD ex");
        String str = jsonElement.getAsString();
        System.out.println(str);
        String[] strs = str.split("\\.");
        String replaced = strs[0] + "." + strs[1].replaceAll("\\d+", "201") + "." + strs[2];
        System.out.println(replaced);
```

How to put it back and create the json?

Comment: regex is clearly the way to go if the patern is always : ["a0.c985.c0"]

Comment: The main question is - how to parse the JSON to get the value of .data.os0.TD ex.value?

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker is a template engine, so it's not the tool for this. Load JSON with some real JSON parser library (like Jackson, or GSon) to a node tree, change the value in that, and then use the same JSON library to generate JSON from the node tree. Also, always avoid doing anything in JSON with regular expressions, as JSON (like most pracitcal languages) can describe the same value in many ways, and so writing truly correct regular expression is totally unpractical.